# Take value from a duplicate row and create a new column pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
Year    Name     Town     Vehicle
2000     John     NYC      Truck
2000     John     NYC      Car
2010     Jim     London     Bike
2010     Jim     London     Car
```

I would like to condense this dataframe to one row per `Year`/ `Name` /`Town`  so that my end result is:

```
Year    Name     Town     Vehicle    Vehicle2
2000     John     NYC      Truck      Car
2010     Jim     London     Bike      Car
```

Im guessing it is some sort of `df.grouby` statement but im not sure how to create the new column. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) for counter with reshape by [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
g = df.groupby(['Year', 'Name','Town']).cumcount()
df1 = (df.set_index(['Year', 'Name','Town', g])['Vehicle']
         .unstack()
         .add_prefix('Vehicle')
         .reset_index())

print (df1)
   Year  Name    Town Vehicle0 Vehicle1
0  2000  John     NYC    Truck      Car
1  2010   Jim  London     Bike      Car
```